# How to create cloud using noise texture on a specific place?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, world, shader-nodes

I'm trying to create clouds using noise texture in world. I would like to keep all the clouds up and not any below horizon. How can I do that? Also, I cannot create clouds using mesh or any other volume nodes cause my pc would explode.

Node setup for world texture and render preview:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the *Generated* texture coordinates, separate the `z` value, and use that information to create and adjust the horizon.

This can also be used to simulate a flat cloud base (i.e. flat-bottomed clouds, which is somewhat related to the concept of a cloud ceiling).

Please see the below node setup for details (note, I adjusted the *Mapping*—highlighted in yellow—to provide a more dramatic example):

[image]
[image: Node Setup]
Hope this helps! Peace and God bless!

Comment: I did not get this. It did nothing. Can you share the .blend file?

Comment: I've edited the post to include a link to the .blend file directly above the screenshot.